# Problem publishing Streamlit app with Heroku

Tags: heroku, streamlit

This is my first time trying to use Streamlit or Heroku. My app runs locally with Streamlit but I hit this error when trying to open the app after publishing it with Heroku:

> 2020-07-22T19:20:13.577096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ewan-app.herokuapp.com request_id=99a5e93d-8caa-458a-bf01-fae69aaa46e9 fwd="81.156.68.48" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

> 2020-07-22T19:20:13.791262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ewan-app.herokuapp.com request_id=e4eea2e8-4fe3-46c4-996e-0d463bb36de0 fwd="81.156.68.48" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

The same thing happens when I change the app script to the following:

```
import streamlit as st
st.write("Hello world!")
```

So I'm guessing it's due to one of the other files. I have the requirements.txt:

```
streamlit==0.63.1
```

Procfile:

```
web:sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

setup.sh:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit

echo "[server]
headless = true
port = $PORT
enableCORS = false
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

I've tried a few different suggestions I've found, like removing the space between web: and sh in Procfile, and tried different layouts in setup.sh, but no luck so far. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a setup.sh and I have a simple Streamlit app working.
My Procfile is slightly different, though:

`web: streamlit run --server.enableCORS false --server.port $PORT app.py`

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed the issue. I'm new to all this, what is the setup.sh for when this seems to be a much better solution anyway? Every tutorial I found used one.